# Amazon login and pay integration with magento

Tags: magento

I would like to integrate Amazon login and pay with Magento. I have gone through the documentation provided by Amazon. Can you give me an idea how I can integrate with Magento.

I believe I need to creat a custom payment module, that I have done. Now main thing is to integrate amazon login and pay with custom module. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting here.
https://amzn.github.io/amazon-payments-magento-plugin/

Use the Pay with Amazon module available on Magento Connect here.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pay-with-amazon-for-magento.html

You don't have to create anything custom. When you successfully install the plugin there will be a new Payment Method and it will also add a "Login with Amazon" in the "Customers" category.

Comment: Please add details not just links

Comment: The links provide a complete walk-through of the installation.

Comment: The links may die its better to add content to the answer and just mention the links for further reference

Comment: True, however, this is Amazon's GitHub site. I do not think it will go away any time soon :)

Comment: Please check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/218121) question about link only answers.

Comment: Unable to get Login with Amazon using Pay with Amazon  extension. I am getting error: 
400 Bad Request
The domain on which you are using the JavaScript SDK has not been whitelisted for your application.
Please help

Comment: @DeepKakkar You need to add your domain to 'Allowed JavaScript Origins' in your Login with Amazon application.